# Caveats with Stdout/Stderr Redirection to Files?

Tags: io-redirection

I was thinking about having the programs that start on login output their stdout/stderr to files, so I can check the stdout/stderr for any of them if necessary.  I also plan to overwrite the last log file instead of appending.

Are there any negative side effects to doing this?  My specific concern is unnecessary hard drive activity.

Comment: If you need the logs, then the HD activity is hardly unnecessary, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't careful about how much logging output your program generates, you can still fill up a disk despite not creating more than one log file, causing all kinds of problems:

1. If run as root, you can literally fill the disk, since that bypasses quotas. Some filesystems also reserve a certain minimum amount of free space for root, to avoid the below problems.
2. If a filesystem is full, you can't even create a temporary file on the disk. If the filesystem you fill is also where some of your common temp space lives (`/tmp`, `/usr/tmp`, `/var/tmp`) programs trying to use that space will likely die if running or fail to start if not.
3. Programs that crash when this happens won't drop [cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_file), if you've set your system up to allow this. That can make it difficult to reduce those programs' sensitivity to low-disk-space conditions, since it makes it harder to discover the specific code path that crashed the program.

You can run [`logrotate`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) along with your program to mitigate the risk of this.

`logrotate` isn't 100% foolproof. It typically runs as a cron job, so if you fill the disk between two `cron` runs, the problem won't be corrected until `logrotate` next runs.

Answer (score 0):

stderr should already be logged to `.xsession-errors`, at least on some Linux distributions.

Of course I am assuming you are solely talking about graphical logins.